# Spark task deserialization time

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm running a Spark SQL job, and when looking at the master UI, task deserialization time can take 12 seconds and the compute time 2 seconds.

Let me give some background:
1- The task is simple: run a query in a PostgreSQL DB and count the results in Spark.
2- The deserialization problem comes when running on a cluster with 2+ workers (one of them the driver) and shipping tasks to the other worker.
3- I have to use the JDBC driver for Postgres, and I run each job with Spark submit.

My questions:

Am I submitting the packaged jars as part of the job every time and that is the reason for the huge task deserialization time? If so, how can I ship everything to the workers once and then in subsequent jobs already have everything needed there?

Is there a way to keep the `SparkContext` alive between jobs (spark-submit) so that the deserialization times reduces?

Anyways, anything that can help not paying des. time every time I run a job in a cluster.

Thanks for your time,

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I know, YARN supports cache application jars so that they are accessible each time application runs: pls refer to [property spark.yarn.jar](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-yarn.html).

To support shared SparkContext between jobs and avoid the overhead of initializing it, there is a project [spark-jobserver](https://github.com/spark-jobserver/spark-jobserver) for this purpose.

Comment: Ah, YARN seems to be the way forward. For the time being I've been running in standalone mode, so it makes sense. Thank you.